MySQL INSERT INTO SELECT ON JOIN
I have a production and staging databasein MySQL.  What I trying to accomplish is to write scripts that I will use to periodically update the staging database from the production database. Here is an example for one table...
INSERT INTO staging.listing SELECT l0.* 
FROM production.listing as l0
left join staging.listing as l1 on l1.id=l0.id
where l1.id is null;

In MySQL Workbench this statement gives me the error...
Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

The id is of course the primary key.  So I am trying to find records that don't exist in the staging database and move them over from production.
I don't understand why this doesn't work.  The table in the staging and production databases is identical.  Same number of columns.  I see in other answers to similar questions to list the columns explicitly.  I don't want to do this.  The tables I want to update in staging have a large number of columns.  Listing them explicitly would be error prone and the script would become immediately obsolete as soon as another column is added to both staging and production.
So what is the proper way to do this?
UPDATE
Indeed the commenters are right.  The tables are not identical.  I thought since there were no outstanding migrations, then they must be identical.  Wrong!  So the script above works...up to a point.
The error I am getting now is
Error Code: 1206. The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size.

The staging table has 300,000 rows and the production table 500,000 rows.  So I am thinking now the only approach is to dump, edit and import.

Are you absolutely positive the tables in the staging and production databases are completely similar? I can't reproduce your error. https://dbfiddle.uk/d_wiQi66

Either they aren't identical or the error is coming from a trigger..

use the Percona cli tools. ie. pt-table-sync . It works in any direction and you can start per cron

@BerndBuffen pt-table-sync requires that the tables have similar columns. So if the problem in this case is that the tables are not in fact identical, pt-table-sync will fail in exactly the same manner. It will also fail if the target table has a trigger that is failing.

If columns list in staging and prod is different, you can list columns directly, to avoid error Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

You want this:
Insert into staging.listing 
Select * from production.listing p
Where not exists
  (select * from staging.listing s where s.id = p.id);

This will work as long as the table structures are the same in both tables.
Note that if you just want staging to be a copy of prod, it's almost always faster to truncate the staging table and just insert all the production rows into staging.
Do the piecemeal copying only when values in stage and prod for rows existing in staging have diverged from prod, and you don't want to overwrite them.

It turns out this is not going to work either.  The error I have now is Error Code: 1206. The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size.  the staging table has 300,000 rows and the production table has 500,000 rows.  So I am thinking now that export/import is really the only way.

Yeah, as I mentioned, truncate and replace.
